# Testing A Function That Always Returns True

Tags: tdd

How would one write a test for the following function?

```
bool IsAnInterger(int ignore) 
{
    return true
}
```

I don't have enough time to iterate over every integer (for the actual code the parameter isn't even an integer).

This is used as part of the Specification Pattern, so that I can implement a Null Object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... testing can be a very effective way to show the presence of bugs, but it is hopelessly inadequate for showing their absence.
>
> -- Edsger W. Dijkstra

I'd say that it's pointless to try to exhaustively black box test this function. It is better to test it in a context similar to where it will be used.

Answer (score 2):

In TDD, you write the test first and that test should specify a specific behavior. So the question should *always* be: What do I expect to happen? - and then write the test to verify that behavior - finally write the solution to make the test pass.

**edit:** Understanding the question

Do you mean that this function is the behavior for a non-existent specification, e.g. a [Null](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) specification? You can of course test this null specification that it behaves in a certain way. At a guess though, this will pretty much be hard-coded one-line return values (if anything). The tests for this null object would then basically only document what the null specification should do. It won't add any other extra business value to the system.

Comment: So how do I write the test for "I expect the function to return true for any value"?

Comment: You can't for any value. You have to specify a value when you call the function. This requires a bit of white-box testing. If for instance you know the boundaries, then you can boundary test. Randomly throwing values in is fragile - the test may work sometimes, but not others. As I said before, there is little business value to testing such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot reasonably test every case, you can use [Mathematical Induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) *as a basis* for your tests. You can't do this algebraically, but you can pick an arbitrary value for *`n`*.

```
#include <limits>
#include <cassert>

bool IsAnInteger(int) 
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    assert(IsAnInteger(std::numeric_limits<int>::min())); // First
    assert(IsAnInteger(0)); // n
    assert(IsAnInteger(1)); // n+1
}
```

### Edit

Hold on!

> for the actual code the parameter isn't even an integer

What is it then?

```
#include <cassert>

template <class T>
bool IsAnInteger(const T&) 
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    assert(IsAnInteger(0)); // First
    assert(IsAnInteger("I am not a number!")); // n
    assert(IsAnInteger(42.0f)); // n+x
}
```

Your function has 100% test coverage and your unit tests accurately document how it behaves. In TDD you only need to write *just enough* code so that your unit tests pass. You're done with this and can move on.

Comment: This is not proper induction. You need to show that if `IsAnInteger(n)` works _for any n_, it also holds for `IsAnInteger(n+1)`, plus a base case. You have only shown it for `n = 0`.

Comment: @Johnysweb: My point is that you have shown it _for a single n_. In order to use induction you must show that it holds for _any n_. That said, it's pretty pointless to use induction here. A direct proof is much clearer.

Comment: @hammar: Have clarified my answer. Thanks.